# android, returning xml data using httpget

Tags: android, xml, http-get

I am new to android and have very limited understanding of the code. I am trying to return xml data from an api on the internet. I have read several enteries about this but none seem to work and they offer little explanation of the code, so I am unable to alter it too much.

Can anybody please explain where I am going wrong and give me a little guidance on what needs to be changed?

Cheers guys

```
package com.example.testingXML;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class Main extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet();
      httpget.setURI(new URI("http://api.inapub.co.uk/venues/postcode/bn23fe/1/?API_Key=7xa3tdmjkhu6jwjvp746zgg4"));


      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
      HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

      BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

      InputStream is = buf.getContent();

      BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

      StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
      while((line = r.readLine()) != null){
        total.append(line + NL);
      }

      r.close();
      String page = r.toString();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you getting response in total ? log.v("testest",total); check it if getting response for api or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1) Please use a separate thread to do your HTTP fetching.  See:
    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

2) Make sure your application is requesting internet permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

3) The easiest way to do this is using a URLConnection

```
URLConnection conn = new URL("http://api.inapub.co.uk/venues/postcode [etc...]").OpenConnection();
```